# Zurb Foundation Abide and AngularJS initialization

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, requirejs, zurb-foundation, abide

I am using both AngularJS and Zurb Foundation.To initialize Foundation you have to make the following call:

```
$(document).foundation()
```

But, when you load a new view using angularjs foundation js is not working anymore and you need to re-initialize Foundation again, i have done it like this:

```
app.run ($rootScope)=>
  $rootScope.$on '$viewContentLoaded', ()=>
    $(document).foundation()
```

When loading the first view, Abide works, but when loading another view using $routeprovider it doesn't work anymore.
Expected Result:

[image]

The result after loading the view:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could also try re-binding Abide's events to the form `$('form_id').foundation({bindings: 'events'});` (Foundation 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice would be wrapping Foundation plugins in angular directives or using only CSS/SASS provided by the framework. The workaround that i found is to include the plugin script in the AngularJS view.Either way AngularJs and Zurb Foundation do not play well together.

Answer (score 0):

The most common practice is to create an angular directive and within the `link` callback call your third party DOM manipulation code

Comment: Tried that, but the plugins crash unfortunately :(

Comment: what does `plugins crash` mean? What errors are thrown? Create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: as you can see abide is not working properly when switching from a view to another.